# How to combine two arrays into one 2D array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

The title basically says it.
Here's the code I'm using:

```
function combine(a1, a2) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i=0; i<a1.length && i<a2.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = [[a1[i]], [a2[i]]];
    }
    return arr;
}
```

However, if I supply the function with:

```
var a1 = ["Hello","Goodbye"];
var a2 = ["Cat","Dog"];
```

The function would return:

```
H,Cat,e,Dog
```

Can anyone explain how I can make it return:

```
Hello,Cat,Goodbye,Dog
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `map` and `join` to get your expected output:

```js
var a1 = ["Hello","Goodbye"];
var a2 = ["Cat","Dog"];

const combine = (one, two) => one.map((a,i)=>[a,two[i]]).join(",")

console.log(combine(a1,a2));
```

Comment: Is this the code you suggest I use?
function combine(a1, a2) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i=0; i<a1.length && i<a2.length; i++) {
        arr = a1.map((a,i)=>[a,a2[i]]).join(",");
    }
    return arr;
}
Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @user57202 I have updated my answer. Now I have created a generic method where I passed two array values to get the exp o/p. You won't need a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use concat method for joining the arrays.

```
  var a1 = ["Hello","Goodbye"];
  var a2 = ["Cat","Dog"];
  
  function combine(a1, a2) {
  return a1.concat(a2);
  }

  var combined_array = combine(a1,a2);
```